# Select by varchar column with IN() part in condition and int value returns all rows

Tags: mysql, varchar

Can someone explain me why with that query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE (tag IN ('willa-lentza', 2016))
```

it return me all rows from `tags` table, but when I put `2016` into quotes it works good ?

`tag` column is `varchar` type.

**SAMPLE ENVIRONMENT**

```
CREATE TABLE  `tags` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `tag`) VALUES
  (1, '2016'),
  (2, 'plum'),
  (3, 'banana'),
  (4, 'apple'),
  (5, 'willa-lentza');
```

I also get the same error as Roland Bouman got:

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'willa-lentza'
```

Comment: Is is a standalone query or a part of a stored procedure?

Comment: Standalone via Mysql Query Browser

Comment: On my `5.1.35`, this returns correct results: `2` records both with and without quotes. Which version do you use?

Comment: I don't get this result. executing this exact script gives me the expected result: i get tags 2016 and willa-lentza back. I am using 5.1.36 CE on windows

Comment: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.42, for pc-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You should never mix quoted and
>   unquoted values in an IN list because
>   the comparison rules for quoted values
>   (such as strings) and unquoted values
>   (such as numbers) differ. Mixing types
>   may therefore lead to inconsistent
>   results.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Answer (score 1):

Interesting...i got this.

```
mysql> select 'a' in (0, 'b');
+-----------------+
| 'a' in (0, 'b') |
+-----------------+
|               1 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a'
```

EDIT: actually i think I can exaplain this one. (because 0 is in the in list, mysql thinks the rest og the in list and also the left hand argument 'a' should all be numbers. Casting 'a' will result in 0, so this will intenally be seen as `0 in (0, 0)`

but I still can't explain the behavior of the OP

Comment: If the integer value is 0, the statement seems to be true. If it is any other integer, it seems to be false.

Comment: See my sample data in first post.

Answer (score 0):

My brief testing does not confirm this behavior.

```
SELECT 'test' IN ('other-string', 2016) /* returns 0 */
```

Not just any string should be able to match an integer. Are you sure you haven't changed anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this behaviour, but it seems that your `varchars` get casted into a `DOUBLEs` and not the other way around.

In this case, the query turns into this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tags
WHERE   CAST(tag AS DOUBLE) /* =0 for non-numeric tags */ IN (CAST('willa-lentza AS DOUBLE) /* = 0 */, 2016)
```

which is always true for all non-numeric tags.

Could you please run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...` on this statement and post the warning here?

To confirm this behavior, you can add another numerical tag:

```
INSERT
INTO    tags
VALUES  (6, '1000')
```

This tag should be returned by neither of the queries.

To avoid this, just always enclose your constants into single quotes so that they are parsed as `CHARs`

Comment: `@hsz`: This is it. `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` should emit another warning with the plan details and code `1003`. Could you please find and post it as well?

Comment: Ah, ok - here you are: `select tags.id AS id, tags.tag AS tag from tags where (tags.tag in (_utf8'willa-lentza',2016))`
Nothing more than that (it is marked as `1003`).

Comment: `@hsz`: Could you please add a numerical tag as shown in the update to my post and run the unquoted query? This tag should not be returned.