# MySQL coding question

Tags: mysql

How would I check for a number like zero `0` in MySQL for example does user equal zero `0`?

Which one if any is the correct one?

```
AND user = 0
AND user = '0'
AND user = '" . 0 . "'
```

Comment: First option would be the way.

Comment: @mhitza what is wrong with the other examples?

Comment: Related: [Does 1 always equal '1' in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134102/does-1-always-equal-1-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on which format the column is. If it is stored as an int, then using `user=0` would be correct.

If the column was stored as a char, then `user='0'` would be correct.

The fundamental difference is that, a char can hold letters/numbers etc. And an int will just hold numbers - and that an int 0, and a char '0' are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

`user = 0` is the way to go if you have an integer based column. The other versions work too. However, the other ones probably require a conversion from string to integer, which is an extra overhead.