# LEFT JOIN statement is not like a subquery with NOT IN?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 simple tables USERS and ORDERS and I want to find USERS who don't have make any order. For each order I have a column `userId` filled. I write a simple query but she doesn't works...

The simple query :

```
select id from USERS where id not in (select userId from ORDERS);
```

Please note that `USERS.id` is a `VARCHAR` like `ORDERS.userId`.

Can someone explain that :

```
> select count(distinct userId) from ORDERS;
+------------------------+
| count(distinct userId) |
+------------------------+
|                   4261 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

> select count(distinct id) from USERS;
+--------------------+
| count(distinct id) |
+--------------------+
|              14960 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

> select id from USERS
> where id not in (select userId from ORDERS);
Empty set (0.47 sec)
```

I have more users than order's users but THE SET IS EMPTY !!! It must be 14960-4261=**10699**

But when I do that :

```
> select count(*)
> from USERS left join ORDERS on ORDERS.userId=USERS.id
> where ifnull(ORDERS.userId,'')='';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    10700 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)
```

It's OK !!! There is just an error for 1 line (propably due to a null or 0 or empty value...)

Maybe I'm tired but after that... I feel like I do not understand anything to MySQL... !!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure as I don't have access to the tables,
but you may try this one: [Select by varchar column with IN() part in condition and int value returns all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064766/select-by-varchar-column-with-in-part-in-condition-and-int-value-returns-all-r)